# Hard to find "ask question" button

Tags: feature-request, design

It seems like the site design is a little harder to use than the other Stack Exchange sites.  Took me a while to find the "Ask question" button.  All of its peers are navigation links, while it is an actual action item, so perhaps it should be a little louder?

[image]

For reference, here are the other Stack Exchange sites I have used:

DBA:
[image]

Stack Overflow:
[image]

Comment: Hot off the presses: https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/home-improvement-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange is currently rolling out new site theme, "responsive design site themes" on all* SE Q&A sites, which basically looks like current Stack Overflow. You can see which sites have received and will soon receive on here: [Rollout of responsive design site themes - Tracking post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post).

As of current writing, DIY.SE is "Not yet in progress". It doesn't mean it won't get the new theme, but because this site is not using a "stock" theme, the designers will have to adjust and incorporate current design elements to the new theme, which certainly take some time.

So, you just need to be patient until this site gets its turn.

Comment: I found it eventually, no rush from me :)  I'm rooting for diy.stackexchange over the existing mess, just pointing out low-hanging fruit that can bend the adoption curve a bit.